# Encrypted Excel workbook as database for program

Tags: excel, vb.net

I'm coding program in VB.NET and at this moment I'm using encrypted Excel workbook as database for this program. So when I run my program, it will open encrypted workbook with updated data and load it into memory. Is this way secure? Is this workbook upon opening accessible by other processes (by meaning if someone want to stole data from that workbook)?
Thanks for answers.

Comment: is it secure? depends on what leave of security you need.  Probably secure enough to stop the most casual of attempts but anyone with google and a spare 10mins can normally workout how to by pass that level security if they wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

The file is secure.

but if you release your .exe publicly, anyone can decompile it, and find the password used to encrypt the workbook.

once they know the password, they can read every workbook created with your program, unless the user can choose their own passwords.

so do not set a hardcoded password in your app code. if the library you use to save the workbook does not have an option to set a custom password, advanced users might know how to get the password.

**alternative solution**

It is recommended to use classes and objects like how .net was intended.

then serialise the object you want to save to XML text.

then you can encrypt and decrypt that text before you save it, using a password that the user can set himself.